# Passing variables to a JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
            if (radioValue) {
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            }
        });
        
    });
    </script>
    
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
```

I want to edit the simple jquery script above to accept the input name (name='gender') as a variable/parameter. How can I do that. instead of literally stating the name.

HTML:

```html
<label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
```

Comment: The name will be on the element that was clicked.  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: `this` ought be good nuff

Comment: Or are you wanting to pass in a variable so it only binds to the radio buttons that are for `gender`?  EDIT: Also `$("input[type='button']")` doesn't match any elements in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var chkType = $('#chkType').val();
    var radioValue = $("input["+chkType+"]:checked").val();
    if (radioValue) {
      alert("Your are: " + radioValue);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.flex-parent{display:flex;}
.flex-child{flex:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>1. Click Male/Female radio buttons. Working normally BUT using a variable.</h3>
<h3>2. In the input box, change "gender" to "size" and click change button, then click the Tall/Short radio buttons</h3>
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="tall" />Tall</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="short" />Short</label>
  </div>
</div><!-- .flex-parent -->
<div>
  <input id="chkType" type="text" value='name="gender"' /><button>Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work. Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for